# Cucumber pass whole example to a step

Tags: java, cucumber, scenarios

I want to pass a whole example to some test step as an Map object. How can it be achieved?

lets say I have scenario

```
Scenario Outline: some description text
When user do something
Then the user should see something
Examples: set 1
  | Param Title |
  | value 1     |
Examples: set 2
  | Param Title | Param Title 2 |
  | value 2     | value 3       |
```

in the step definition of `When user do something` I want a map that would have map `{"Param Title":"value 1"}` for first example and `{"Param Title":"value 2","Param Title 2":"value 3"}` for the second example. Is there any way to do that in cucumber or my only option is to write same scenario multiple times for each example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of writing a step definition is trivial compared to the complexity you are adding by trying to pass your map into a generic step def.

If you implement all your step definitions as single calls to a helper method it really doesn't matter if you have lots of step definitions that do the same thing. When you follow this pattern your step definitions perform one function, they translate a string phrase into a method call.

Let me give you some examples

```
Given I am logged in
Given I am logged in as an admin
Given Fred is logged in
Given Bill is logged in
Given Sam is logged in as an admin
```

Now you would probably want to write just one step definition for all of these, but that is actually a mistake and a false optimisation. Its much simpler to do the following (all examples are in ruby)

```
Given 'I am logged in' do
  @i ||= create_user
  login as: @i
end

Given 'I am logged in as an admin' do
  @i ||= create_admin
  admin_login as: @i
end

Given 'Fred is logged in' do
  @fred ||= create_user(first_name: 'Fred')
  login as: @fred
end

Given 'Bill is logged in' do
  @bill ||= create_user(first_name: 'Bill')
  login as: @fred
end
  
Given 'Sam is logged in as an admin' do
  @sam ||= create_admin(first_name: 'Sam')
  login as: @sam
end
```

All the work here is being done by the helper methods (create_user, create_admin, login, admin_login), so it doesn't matter if you have twenty step definitions that do login so long as they all use the helper methods to do the work you have no real code duplication, and you have simplicity and consistency.

This is a completely different approach to the one you are currently taking. But a valid answer to any cuke question involving doing complex things with steps and step definitions is to stop trying to do complex things and instead more simple things.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. I never thought of this way. But implementing it in my case is gonna be much much more complex. The reasons are: 
1. I am trying to fill dynamic forms.
2. All of those forms contain min of 10 parameters
3. Some Parameters are optional
4. In some tests they are used in other they are not
5. Many of the form selections append different form for each type
6. Also for same form their are different variants

Comment: So you can imagine how doing this in my case would mean explosion of steps, classes and methods to implements different variations. So I came up with an idea to write a simple class which checks the task name and compare it with keys of the Map to see if it exist. If yes perform it (like select, enter click etc something) other wise ignore it. Using it I am doing the same form filling in much much lesser cost and great reusability.

Comment: Now only problem remaining is Scenarios. I cannot send variables in a dynamic way. So which mean I have to either write same scenario for different variations or do something complicated unless I can pass current example which would make my overall code much simpler

Comment: So you need to find out WHY some fields are filled in some tests and not filled in others. Then gives names to the sets of parameters. Things like good_data, bad_data, options_supplied etc. etc.. Then make methods that deal with sets of parameters e.g. fill_in_good_data etc.. Do this will and you will end up with a small hierarchy of fill methods that you can use to populate your forms with single simple step defs, and none of the details of which fields you fill in need to appear in the scenario.

Comment: This idea looks interesting. So basically what I will be doing is loading data from some file instead, right? And then use some variable from examples to load the correct data? I am new to Cucumber and Test Automation in general. Do you think it would be good idea to load from files? As it would add another dependency and Would also require me to automatically inject the right data to right scenario plus the test file handling.

Comment: No I don't think its a good idea to load from files, because control moves out of source (where it is visible) into files (where it is less visible). Most of the time you can just load data from code either by creating fake data, or by using constants, The data really isn't that relevant the important things is the intention of the data i.e. what are you trying to do when you work with a particular set of data.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I went with this idea and it works great. Although I went a little of course by using json file instead since upper management insisted. As the visibility of parameter values was not that big deal because of serenity framework's detailed report.

Comment: Cool, please consider accepting the answer if you found it useful

Comment: @diabolist, what if I want to grab the current whole row of the example because I want to avoid a step with very long line, e.g. my Examples table will be having more than 10 columns.

Comment: Don't use example tables. The whole point of this approach is to push down where you define what the parameters are and what there values are from the feature to the step definitions. To do this you need to find the reason for each row in your example table. Use this reason to discover a name and then use the Name in a unique scenario in your feature file. In your step defs you can have a helper method where you define your params in a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You may write like below in feature file where Param Title is defined as Column

```
When user do something <Param Title>
```

In Step Definition, you may write. in this way, you don't have to write again and again scenarios and you can write multiple examples as multiple rows in one example set

```
@When("user do something ([^\"]*)")
public void useractivity(String Title){

}
```

Comment: My question is how to send the whole example to step. Like some steps accept variable number of parameters. But because of how the scenario is written the parameters have to be defined that the step should use

Comment: you can write as below   When User do Something
|Param Title|<Param Title>|
|Param Title2|<Param Title2>

Comment: Again, I need to pass variable number of parameters. Lets say for one example they are 2. For next example they could be 1 or 7 or 3. Doing as you suggested require listing down the parameters under step. Once listed down it will pass only those except if I create new scenario to list different parameters.

Comment: As many parameters are there that many rows would be there in the data table under the step. In Stepdefinition it would take as a List  and with as many rows that many key and value would be added

Comment: Let's take an example of yours. In the table, you pass with 2 Parameters as mentioned in my previous comment.in Example one, you pass a blank value to Param Title 2, and in Example set 2 you pass a value for both Example Param Title.